# Blank Screen After Migration to New Server

Tags: database, server-migration

I have just migrated my site to the live server and I have a blank screen for both the site and the control panel.

I have added the dbtest.php file to my root and there is no error.

I have turned on debugging and I am getting the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /homepages/33/d79609761/htdocs/gaelic_teachers/bord-na-gaidhlig/expressionengine/core/EE_Config.php on line 40

Can anyone advise on what the issue may be?

Thanks.
Stephen.

Comment: Post the contents of your config/config.php file.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your reply. I managed to fix the issue, it was to do with the php settings on my hosting account.